# Jetpack Compose TopAppBar wrong color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to have a white top app bar using Jetpack Compose but the color is grey instead of white.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = Colors(
            primary = colorResource(R.color.colorPrimary),
            primaryVariant = colorResource(R.color.colorPrimaryVariant),
            secondary = colorResource(R.color.colorSecondary),
            secondaryVariant = colorResource(R.color.colorSecondaryVariant),
            background = colorResource(R.color.white),
            surface = colorResource(R.color.white),
            error = colorResource(R.color.failure),
            onPrimary = colorResource(R.color.colorOnPrimary),
            onSecondary = colorResource(R.color.colorOnSecondary),
            onBackground = colorResource(R.color.colorOnBackground),
            onSurface = colorResource(R.color.colorOnSurface),
            onError = colorResource(R.color.white),
            isLight = false
        ),
        typography = Typography(),
        shapes = Shapes(),
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun TestTopBar() {
    AppTheme {
        TopBar(title = R.string.common_country, actions = actions())
    }
}

@Composable
fun actions(): @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {
    IconButton(onClick = {}) { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, "Search") }
}

@Composable
fun TopBar(title: Int, actions: @Composable (RowScope.() -> Unit) = {}) {
    TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
        //CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high) {
        Box {
            // navigation icon
            Row(Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, "Back")
                }
            }

            // title
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .alpha(1f),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    text = stringResource(title),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                )
            }

            // actions
            Row(
                Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                content = actions
            )
        }
        //}
    }
}
```

I've set the surface as white in my theme. I've also set the background color of the top app bar as white. Still, the preview display a light grey instead of white.

[image: TopAppBar]

Comment: try to add white color for top most box in your __TopAppBar__

Comment: I think the TopAppBar is the Primary color? Maybe try to change that?